# How do I rearrange values in different columns in an R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe of customer data. It has 3 columns for phone numbers.
Something similar to the below table:

```
x <- data.frame("Phone1" = c(123,"NULL",245), "Phone2" = c("NULL","NULL",325 ), "Phone3" = c(847,219,"NULL"))
> View(x)
> x
  Phone1 Phone2 Phone3
1    123   NULL    847
2   NULL   NULL    219
3    245    325   NULL
```

Now , I want to rearrange the values in these columns such that the NON-NULL values come first, and the NULL values of each record are pushed to the last. This is how I want my output to be:

```
Phone1 Phone2 Phone3
1    123    847   NULL
2    219   NULL   NULL
3    245    325   NULL
```

I tried doing this with a series of if statements, but it takes a lot of time, since my original dataframe has a lot of records. I was wondering if there is a simpler method using dplyr or other packages that can help with this.

Comment: Your exected result is inconsistent with your input data: `847` is in `Phone3`, not `Phone2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` and `c` with indexes for `y!="NULL"` and `y=="NULL"`:

```
t(apply(x, 1, function(y) {i <- y=="NULL"; c(y[!i], y[i])}))
#     [,1]  [,2]   [,3]  
#[1,] "123" "847"  "NULL"
#[2,] "219" "NULL" "NULL"
#[3,] "245" "325"  "NULL"
```

and in case the order does not matter (Thanks to @Daniel-o !):

```
t(apply(x, 1, sort))
#     [,1]  [,2]   [,3]  
#[1,] "123" "847"  "NULL"
#[2,] "219" "NULL" "NULL"
#[3,] "245" "325"  "NULL"
```

Or with colnames:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(asplit(x, 1), sort))
#     Phone1 Phone3 Phone2
#[1,] "123"  "847"  "NULL"
#[2,] "219"  "NULL" "NULL"
#[3,] "245"  "325"  "NULL"
```

Comment: Or if we do not care about maintaining the original order we can simplify to `t(apply(x,1, function(x) x[order(x)]))`

Comment: @DanielO Thanks! I have inserted the shorter `t(apply(x, 1, sort))`

Answer (score 0):

a bit long solution, but does what expected using tidyverse.

I'm guessing you likely have several more columns in your data than just the phone columns. So this piece of code should *only* change your "PhoneX" columns and no other columns.

The making of the `id` column can be omitted if you already have a column uniquely identifying your customer, in that case replace `id` with that in the `group_by(id)` function.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

x <- data.frame(Phone1 = c(123,"NULL",245, 456), 
                Phone2 = c("NULL","NULL",325, 893), 
                Phone3 = c(847,219,"NULL", 241))

x %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% #make unique identifier
  gather(phone, nr, starts_with("Phone")) %>% #make long format of phone cols
  filter(nr != "NULL") %>% #remove NULLs
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(phone = paste0("Phone", row_number())) %>% 
  spread(phone, nr, fill = "NULL") %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>      id Phone1 Phone2 Phone3
#>   <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1     1 123    847    NULL  
#> 2     2 219    NULL   NULL  
#> 3     3 245    325    NULL  
#> 4     4 456    893    241
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>